# How do I include css from npm in Angular2

Tags: angular

This has been surprisingly hard to find an answer to, please point out if I'm not searching right and this is a duplicate question.

I have an Angular2 (2.0.0-beta.14) app and am having issues including a 3rd party css file. I've downloaded materialize-css via npm and I can see the file is at `node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.css`.

I would like this css file to be visible to my entire application.

At the highest level, I've tried including it in my `index.html` head section `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.css" media="screen">`, but can't figure out where it's being served or even if it's being served.

At a lower level, I've tried defining it in the `styleUrls` token of the app initiation.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myApp',
  providers: [],
  pipes: [],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: 'app/henna.html',
  styleUrls: ['materialize.css']
})
```

I've tried various different styleUrls trying to find the file, but it seems the problem might be that the file is not accessible.

Please let me know any more info that is needed to help, this is my first application that I've used Angular2.

Comment: Are you using the configuration from the official [5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)?

Comment: @CosminAbabei I started by cloning https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed Anything in particular you're wanting to know?

Comment: I was interested in knowing what kind of structure you are using. I'm not sure what's wrong since I could install `materialize-css` with no problems after cloning `angular2-seed`. Have you made any structural changes to this seed?

Comment: nothing structural, just added a few new components. After `npm install materialize-css` what did you do to have the css file loaded?

Comment: Just copy pasted your link tag and it worked `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.css" media="screen">`. What error are you getting? 404?

Comment: weird, yeah I'm getting a 404

Comment: absolutely no idea why this is working for you, I tried a fresh install from angular-seed and had the same issue but ... I figured it out. Answer coming shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with webpack not bundling my files how I was expecting (I had never used webpack before). I needed to install the correct webpack loaders for css and font files, import materialize, and then the files were being included.

After installing the correct loaders (`npm install css-loader` `npm install file-loader`), in `webpack.config.js` I needed to modify the module object.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, loader : 'file-loader'},
    ]
  }
```

in the `vendor.js` file, I needed to import the materialize js and css

```
import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.css'
import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.js'
```